# I need to gain access to an Outlook PST file that grew over 2gb

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2007, pst

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Outlook 2007: “The set of folders cannot be opened” PST has reached its maximum size](https://superuser.com/questions/340254/outlook-2007-the-set-of-folders-cannot-be-opened-pst-has-reached-its-maximum)

Edit:  This is not a duplicate.  The other question suggests using pst2gb.exe but as I mention below I cannot find that tool.  Microsoft's own website no longer has it.   I also can't use the 'compact' method as that requires one first to be able to import the pst file into outlook, which I can't do.

I have a user in my organisation who has an outlook PST file that grew over 2gb and therefore became un-open-able in Outlook.  I did search google for this.  There is a microsoft article that suggests using a tool called 'pst2gb.exe' and then links to a page that no longer exists.

Where can I find that tool?  Or,  preferably,  is there a better way to do this known by the gurus at superuser.com that does not have the disadvantage of possibly losing data from the pst file?

Comment: Thanks,  but that article links to the article I mention, with the dead link to the actual tool.  It also mentions the 'compact' method, which might be no good to me if I can't even open the file.

Comment: best I can find is this: http://www.slipstick.com/problems/pst-repair/repair-a-2gb-personal-folders-or-offline-folders-file

Answer (score 1):

Don't know about that tool, but here is a tool provided by Microsoft to deal with that issue - [Oversized PST and OST crop tool](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/296088). You may want to make a copy of the PST before you attempt a repair.

> NOTE: Use the tool to create a truncated copy of the .pst file. The copy that is left after the tool completes does not have all the original data because the tool cuts a user defined amount of data from the file.

Comment: That's the article I was refering to.  It links to the tool, but the page it links to is no longer available.

Comment: Well, crud! Didn't realize that. You could try [this](http://www.podnutz.com/forums/viewtopic.php?t=6245). There are some great suggestions in the thread.

Comment: Thanks,  but most of the suggestions in that thread are unworkable.  Some suggest deleting stuff from the pst, which I can't do because I can't get into it.  Others suggest other tools, which you have to pay for...  I'll keep reading though, and I have downloaded one tool which I will try.