# I need access to an oversized PST file but the pst2gb.exe tool is no longer available and compact won't work

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2007, pst

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [I need to gain access to an Outlook PST file that grew over 2gb](https://superuser.com/questions/459062/i-need-to-gain-access-to-an-outlook-pst-file-that-grew-over-2gb)

I had to try and make the title specific so that this question wouldn't get closed as a duplicate of other questions.  Other questions answer by suggesting pst2gb.exe or the 'compact' feature in outlook.

I am unable to find pst2gb.exe because microsoft's own article (http://support.microsoft.com/kb/296088) now links to a page that is no longer available.

I am unable to use the 'compact' tool in outlook because that first requires you to be able to import the pst file.  The pst file won't import in the first place as it is too large.  Catch-22.

So,  does anyone know where else I can get the pst2gb.exe tool?

Does anyone know of a third way of getting into an over 2gb pst file?

Comment: This is the same exact question you asked [HERE](http://superuser.com/q/459062/97028).

Comment: Please do not simply create a new question when your old one gets ignored, edit your old question to improve it, make it better and flag it to be re-opened.

Comment: It wasn't ignored.  It was closed as a duplicate.

Comment: CharlieRB it was closed!  THe person who closed it didn't spot that it wasn't actually a duplicate.  I have explained why the answers given in the duplicate did not work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### PST2GB

Download the zip with the `pst2gb.exe`, DLLs, and read-me files from my [Dropbox](http://db.tt/hAcGpetP).

### SplitPST

You can use the tools provided from [SplitPST](http://www.splitpstfree.com/freescan.php):

> You can use split PST software to split PST file outlook 2007 into smaller files. This software ensures that no data is lost while splitting your PST file.

- [Download Software for PST Repair + Split PST + PST Password Recovery](http://semsols123.bluesquad.revenuewire.net/pst-repair/download)
- [Download Software to Split PST](http://send.onenetworkdirect.net/z/331625/CD141044)

User guide [here](http://www.splitpstfree.com/userguide.php).