# Can't work with Outlook 365 IMAP account that has this message "Message store has reached its maximum size", no scanpst.exe

Tags: microsoft-outlook, office365, file-corruption

I have a Google Workspace Business Standard account configured by IMAP on Outlook 365 on a Windows 10 Pro machine.

Outlook says that "Message store has reached its maximum size" and I can't delete any email, archive, nor empty the Trash, because the whole account became unresponsive. The .OST has about 49 GB on disk.

Apparently Microsoft 365 does not come with `scanpst.exe` anymore. I downloaded a tool which did nothing and does not have the specific case defined. Tried with "Outlook stops responding", "Outlook can't send or receive email" and "Other", to no avail (messages are in Spanish, so may not be exactly as they appear to English speaking users).

I'm at the point where I think it's better to create a new profile and start from scratch, the user already deleted 30GB of email on the gmail.com interface.

Any other suggestion?

**Edit**- I already compacted the file, as suggested here: [Outlook 2007: "The set of folders cannot be opened" PST has reached its maximum size](https://superuser.com/questions/340254/outlook-2007-the-set-of-folders-cannot-be-opened-pst-has-reached-its-maximum;) it didnt work.

Comment: Look in Program Files   (64-bit)  for Microsoft Office\root\Office16 and scanpst may be there. It is there only my own Windows 11 Office 365 machines

Comment: I did search for it with Everything, but what I found was not executable. I'll check again.

Comment: Something wrong with the OS perhaps.  I looked around all my machines.

Comment: Scanpst will do nothing on .ost files.

Comment: @Ramhound So I just toss it and download again via IMAP?

Comment: That is probably the best thing to do. Delete the OST, restart, and download again

Comment: It was the only option that worked at the end. Probably good to make a copy of the .ost before removing it from outlook because it instantly deleted it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a couple of things to solve the large OST file issue, such as:

1. Rename the local-size OST file and let the server create a fresh OST file for you.
2. Creating a new profile would be a nice step, because a large OST can also corrupt the Outlook profile.
3. Open Outlook from OWA and archive all the old emails, or delete the unnecessary items that are actually not important to you.
4. You can use the sync setting to control the amount of data you want to download in the local OST file by adjusting its date range and capping the OST file size.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried creating a new email Profile from Control Panel? (Go to Control Panel > Mail > Show Profiles)

It is recommended that you remove the email account first and then create a new email profile and re-connect the account.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Finally I removed the account from the Profile and re-added it. I had two other accounts on the same profile so this was the easier course of action.